# Clear style on input

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css

I have formatted input fields with CSS, but my submit button now is 400px width and I don't know how to make it smaller.

**@post form:**

```
 <% create_url = {:url=>{:action=>"create"}} if @post.new_record? %>
      <% form_for @post, :html => { :multipart => true } do |t| %>
        <b><%= t.label :title, 'Virsraksts:' %></b><br />
        <%= t.text_field :title %><br /><br />
        <b><%= t.label :content, 'Teksts:' %></b><br />
        <%= t.text_area :content %><br /><br />
        <b><%= t.label :bildes, 'Pievienot bildes:' %></b><br />
        <%= f.file_field :bildes %><br /><br /><br />
        <%= t.submit %>
<% end %>
        <%end%>
```

**CSS:**

```
input {
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

textarea {
  width: 400px;
}
```

Please help me guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `input` selector also selects your submit button, if you only want textfields do a `input[type=text]` in your css

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS `input[type="text"]` to specify `<input type="text" />`

Comment: Thank you, but you were second who answered right. Buy anyway Thanks! :)